# How to change view state?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Following is a simplified version of my mxml:

```
<s:BorderContainer>
 <s:states>
  <s:State name="create"/>
  <s:State name="edit"/>
 </s:states>
 <s:transitions>
  <s:Transition fromState="create" toState="edit">
   <s:Sequence target="{creation}">
    <s:Fade/>
    <s:RemoveAction/>
   </s:Sequence>
  </s:Transition>
 </s:transitions>
 <comp:create includeIn="create"/>
 <comp:edit includeIn="edit"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Within `<comp:create includeIn="create"/>` I have a button that once clicked calls: `this.parent.currentState='edit'`. But for some reason I get the following error:
"A term is undefined and has no properties..." which points me to the line `this.parent.currentState='edit'`. Anyone what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that [this.parent] is pointing to the [<s:BorderContainer/>] ??

Comment: +1 to @adrian .  I suggest running the code in debug mode and see what the state of that line is.  We'd probably have to review the "create" code to help more.

Comment: I agree with #Flextras . Please post all the code so we can also debug. One thing is certain: at that line one of the following are null [this , this.parent, this.parent.currentState]

Comment: Thanks @Adrian and @Flextras for the help; the issue ended up being that I moved [this.parent] within an event handler, hence it was no longer pointing to the [s:BorderContainer/>]. I inexplicably didn't catch it right off the bat; once I ran the code through debug mode with a couple of trace commands, the issue was obvious.

Comment: You may want to add the solution in as an answer to your question so others who are searching for the same thing will see that your question was answered and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate this a lot better.

Make sure your component re-dispatches the click event, and you can do this, which is much nicer (and also has the benefit of not tying your create and edit components to your BorderContainer)

something like...

```
<s:BorderContainer id="contentHolder">
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="create"/>
        <s:State name="edit"/>
    </s:states>
    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="create" toState="edit">
            <s:Sequence target="{creation}">
                <s:Fade/>
                <s:RemoveAction/>
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>

    <comp:create includeIn="create" click="contentHolder.currentstate='edit'"/>
    <comp:edit includeIn="edit" click="contentHolder.currentstate='create'"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```